# Does Codeigniter Autoloads Libraries/helpers on every Http Request

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I enabled profiling in my application based on Codeigniter and i got some surprising results.

On further debugging i realized that the following values was very high even for a static pages like aboutus etc which has no DB interaction or php processing
Loading Time: Base Classes 
Controller Execution Time 
Total Execution Time

I tried playing with the config file and realized that if i removed the autoloading of several models and libraries the values of the above 3 variables goes significantly down

I was assuming that if something is autoloaded once it remains in the memory. Is this right ?

Also looking at the results if i have a model which is required 70% of the time in the code should i still not autoload it and load only when required to improve performance.

Is there any other alternative

Answer (score 2):

Autoloading it is not something that runs once and is stored in memory for all requests.  Every time a request is made the index.php in the root kicks off and it has to load everything from scratch each time. The benefit of Autoloading is that you don't have to bother loading it yourself everytime you want to call it since Codeigniter already did it for you.  It makes coding easier.  You should autoload whenever you use modules everytime a user does any request or to make certain functionality global.  For example, I use `url_helper` in all of my views so I just autoloaded it so I didn't have to load it manually myself.

Autoloading a model will not improve performance.

To manually load stuff see the http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Agreed !! But suppose if url_helper was needed in only 60-70% of views, should i not autoload to ensure performance in the rest 30-40% of the views ? Is there any best practice/standard recommended

Comment: The performance hit for loading `url_helper` is so tiny it dosen't matter to me.  Including it helps me avoid bugs where I forget to load it.  Technically though if I didn't load it, it would be one less thing the server needs to do.  I guess it's a matter of style/opinion on if you should use manual loading or autoloading, but I think most folks who just say autoload it.